# Attribute changes in directive not reflected

Tags: angularjs, videogular

Template which uses video-player directive:

```
<form action="#" name="postLinkForm" id="postLinkForm" ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()" novalidate>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" ng-hide="postLinkForm.link.$valid">
        <input ng-model="vm.tumblrLink" class="mdl-textfield__input" name="link" ng-change="vm.isValid(postLinkForm.$valid)" type="url" ng-pattern="vm.pattern" required>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2">Tumblr Link e.x http://example.tumblr.com/post/142553237362/</label>
        <span class="mdl-textfield__error" ng-show="postLinkForm.link.$dirty && postLinkForm.link.$invalid">This has to be a tumblr post url</span>
      </div>
      <div class="popupVideoContainer" ng-show="postLinkForm.link.$valid && vm.videoData">
        <video-player video-data="vm.config"></video-player>
      </div>
</form>
```

Controller for the template above:

```
function tumblrLink ($scope, $sce, $uibModalInstance, tumblrVideoData) {
    var vm = this;


    vm.validity = false;

    vm.videoData = {};

    vm.tumblrLink = "";


    vm.config = {
            sources: [
                {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(vm.videoData.src), type: "video/mp4"},
            ],
            tracks: [
                {
                    src: "",
                    kind: "",
                    srclang: "",
                    label: "",
                    default: ""
                }
            ],
            theme: "/videogular-themes-default/videogular.css",
            plugins: {
                poster: vm.videoData.poster
            }
        };


    vm.isValid = function (valid) {
      if (valid) {
        vm.validity = true;

        vm.videoData = tumblrVideoData.postVideo(vm.tumblrLink);

      }
    };

  }
```

Video-player directive:

```
function videoPlayer () {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: '/common/directives/videoPlayer/videoPlayer.template.html',
      scope: {
        videoData: "="
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('videoData', function (newVal, oldVal) {
          console.log(newVal);
        });
      }

    };
  }
```

First, user will enter a link into the inputbox (name="link). If the link is valid, I will post the link to some API and get some data back, which will be then set to vm.videoData. vm.config relies on data on vm.videoData. If vm.videoData is updated, vm.config is supposed to be updated, and then the attribute video-data in the video-player directive will get updates as well.

The directive video-player will show if the link is valid i.e. passing the ng-pattern. The problem is that, after vm.videoData got the data back from the API, vm.config does not seem to be updated, or at least the attribute video-data does not receive the update. And I have already applied scope.$watch to watch changes on vm.config.

What's the problem?

---

video-player template:

```
<videogular vg-theme="videoData.theme">
  <vg-media vg-src="videoData.sources"
      vg-tracks="videoData.tracks">
  </vg-media>

  <vg-controls>
    <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
    <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
    <vg-scrub-bar>
      <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
    </vg-scrub-bar>
    <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
    <vg-volume>
      <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
      <vg-volume-bar></vg-volume-bar>
    </vg-volume>
    <vg-fullscreen-button></vg-fullscreen-button>
  </vg-controls>

  <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
  <vg-poster vg-url='videoData.plugins.poster'></vg-poster>
</videogular>
```

The directive does not have controller.

Comment: How are you updating the values on `videoPlayer.template.html`?

Comment: @Lex using the videoData

Comment: Try using controller as syntax on your directive template and add `bindToController: true` and `controller: 'tumblrLink as vm'` (or whatever your controller name is - it's hard to tell because you haven't shown that in your question) to your directive. I think the issue is that you're trying to mix `controller as` and `$scope` and it's creating an isolate scope that is local to the directive.

Comment: @Lex, the directive doesn't have controller. The controller is for the template which uses the video-player directive. When I manually set vm.config.plugins.poster in the controller, the directive received the new update. But when set vm.config.sources[0].src to something, the directive didn't get it. So I think it's not about scope problem.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the vm.config inside vm.isValid().
And then I changed

```
<div class="popupVideoContainer" ng-show="postLinkForm.link.$valid && vm.videoData">
```

to

```
<div class="popupVideoContainer" ng-if="postLinkForm.link.$valid && vm.videoData">
```

That way, vm.config will receive the new update first then be passed to video-data attribute. And angular won't complain about emptiness of vm.config when starting up since I added ng-if.

I still don't know if the directive can receive updates from vm.config or not, but at least it solved my problem.